# python3.2 ICMP listener throws errors

Tags: sockets, udp, python-3.2

I am listening to posts from a GPS unit.  In wireshark i see the posts from my devices.  However in my python code i am not catching them.  Here is the code I used.  It is nearly verbatim from [pydocs/sockets](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/socket.html#example).  I get many replies from other things on my network but I do not see my divice ip.

```
#HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
HOST = ''
SENDER = '166.161.24.104'
PORT = 22335
BUFFSIZE = 1024
TIMEOUT = 60 # seconds

import socket

# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 22335))

# Include IP headers
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# receive all packages
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

while True:
    # receive a package
    ans, addr = s.recvfrom(BUFFSIZE)
    print(addr[0])

# disabled promiscuous mode
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

this posts a list of all ip addresses that are talking on my network.

Comment: Are you running this with admin privileges?

Comment: Yes, my command prompt says:  Administrator: Command Prompt  on it's title bar,  my command within the prompt is:  python3 run.py

Comment: Looks like you are copying example from the bottom of http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html. Why did you remove some of the code?

Comment: Yes this is based on the last example in [pydocs/socket](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/socket.html) The `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)` 3rd argument is for IP protocol.  My code uses ICMP.  When I changed mine to ICMP, the `sockopt` & `ioctl` threw errors as well

Comment: ICMP doesn't know anything about ports. Try `bind`-ing to port `0`.

Comment: changed line 12 to `s.bind((HOST, 0))` it listens for 60 seconds and then times out without printing any results.  any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm, put back the `s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)` line maybe?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16655/discussion-between-posop-and-nikolai-n-fetissov)

Comment: Sorry, missed your char invitation. I don't have anything else to add - I don't have a windows machine to test.